# nativescript-contacts throw error

Tags: plugins, nativescript

Error: Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{c896ebc 5117:org.nativescript.Jztong/u0a11
1} (pid=5117, uid=10111) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines in your `app/App_Resources/Android/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

If you are using android v6 you should requires permission at runtime, you can use [nativescript-permissions](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-permissions) plugin.

```
var perm = permissions.requestPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, "I need write Contact permission!");
            perm.then(() => {
                //addContact();
            }).catch(() => {
                alert("Oops, No permissions to write contact!");
            });
```